# How to get date in DDMMYYYY format in Tcl?

Tags: datetime, tcl

I am creating a TCL script which creates a log file. The time and date are made part of the log file name.

This is what I have at present:

```
  set fname_date [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%d-%h-%y}]
  set fname_time [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%H%M%S}]

  set    log_fname "test_log"
  append log_fname "_$fname_time"
  append log_fname "_$fname_date"
  append log_fname ".dat"
```

This gives the filename as:

```
test_log_155838_23-Aug-22.dat
```

However, I need the date to be all numbers so the filename looks like this instead:

```
life_test_log_155838_230822.dat
```

How to get the current date in DDMMYY format from TCL? I am not sure what format string to use to do this.

Comment: Nit picking: I would suggest to format the date and time in a single command, or store the output of `clock seconds` in a variable and use that in both commands. Otherwise you run the (very slight) risk that you get values for two different days on subsequent invocations. That would make the created file name off by a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clock format` details are here:

- https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm

DDMMYY format is `%d%m%y`

DDMMYYYY format is `%d%m%Y`

Comment: are you sure about the %C at the end of the first line?

Comment: Aye, should be y not C. 
%C = First two digits of the four-digit year (19 or 20). 
%y = Year without century (00 - 99).

Comment: thanks, I corrected to answer from `%C` to `%y`.   That makes more sense, the "century".

Answer (score 1):

Long form, your code adapted

```
set fname_date [clock format [clock seconds] -format %d%m%y]
set fname_time [clock format [clock seconds] -format %H%M%S]

set    log_fname "test_log"
append log_fname "_$fname_time"
append log_fname "_$fname_date"
append log_fname ".dat"

puts $log_fname
```

Short form

```
set log_fname "life_test_log_[clock format [clock seconds] -format %H%M%S]_[clock format [clock seconds] -format %d%m%y].dat"

puts $log_fname
```

See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/clock.html

Comment: Using a single `[clock format [clock seconds] -format %H%M%S_%d%m%y]` would be even shorter.

Comment: I am not a TCL expert so wrote code that is easier on the eyes, but you are correct.